# Trying to print a linked array, A student may have none or many jobs. printStudentDetails prints each student plus x number of job objects

Tags: java

Like in a library a student can borrow n books. I want to print from two arrays 'students[]' and 'currentJobs[]' so the output is for each student - ID1, name, job1, job2. ID2, name, (no jobs). ID3, job1.

I have created a nested for loop but dont know how to code the link. The common field is studentID so i need the outer loop to getstudentID and compare each studentID on the inner loop(array) and print details for each match

```
 public void displayStudentsReport()
   {
      System.out.println("***** Display Students Report *****");
      System.out.println();

      for (int i = 0; i < indexCount; i++)
      {
         students[i].printStudentDetails();
         // print job details for each student
         for (int j = 0; j < indexNo; j++)
         {
            currentJobs[j].printJobDetails();
         }
      }
   }

   public void printStudentDetails()
   {
      System.out.println("Printing from Student class");
      System.out.printf("%-25s%-40s\n", "Student ID: ", studentID);
      System.out.printf("%-25s%-40s\n", "Name: ", name);
      System.out.println();
   }

   public void printJobDetails()
   {
      System.out.printf("%-25s%-40s\n", "Job: ", jobTitle);
      System.out.printf("%-25s%-4.1f", "Current Working Hours: ", totalHours);
      System.out.println("hrs");
      System.out.printf("%-25s%-40s\n", "Employer: ", employer);
      System.out.println();
   }
```

Expected results explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little fix of what you did. In the second list you should check if it is the correct student from list one.

```
public void displayStudentsReport()
{
  System.out.println("***** Display Students Report *****");
  System.out.println();

  for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
  {
     String comp;
     comp = students[i].getStudentID();
     students[i].printStudentDetails();
     // print job details for each student
     boolean studentHasJob = false;
     for (int j = 0; j < currentJobs.length; j++)
     {
        if(currentJobs[j].getStudentID().equalsIgnoreCase(comp)) {
            studentHasJob = true;
            currentJobs[j].printJobDetails();
        }
     }
     if(!studentHasJob){
         System.out.println("Student " + comp + " has no jobs");
     }
  }


  }
```

And I added a small boolean if you want to print something specific if the student does not have a job.

Hope this is what you are looking for !

--- Edit

So I went over the code again because I thought there was a performance issue here. In fact in the code you pass over the currentJobs array many times. Exactly students.length * currentJobs.length times. Which is a lot. So here is a preview of what could be done better :

```
private void displayStudentsReport() {
    System.out.println("***** Display Students Report *****");
    System.out.println();

// build map of <StudentId : List of job for this student>
// perf is much better here because you pass on the job list only once
// whereas before you passed (students.length * currentJobs.length) times
Map<String, List<Job>> jobByStudent = new HashMap<>();
for(Job currentJob : currentJobs) {
    if(jobByStudent.containsKey(currentJob.getStudentID())) {
        jobByStudent.get(currentJob.getStudentID()).add(currentJob);
    } else {
        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        jobs.add(currentJob);
        jobByStudent.put(currentJob.getStudentID(), jobs);
    }
}

for(Student student : students) {
    String comp = student.getStudentID();
    student.printStudentDetails();

    if(jobByStudent.containsKey(comp)) {
        for(Job job : jobByStudent.get(comp)) {
            job.printJobDetails();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Student " + comp + " has no jobs");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: OK i understand that the first method iterates through the jobs array once for each object in the students array. We have not learned about maps as yet. Thanks for the  info. Different way to do for loops also

Answer (score 0):

```
public void displayStudentsReport()
   {
      System.out.println("***** Display Students Report *****");
      System.out.println();

      for (int i = 0; i < indexCount; i++)
      {
         String comp;
         comp = students[i].getStudentID();
         students[i].printStudentDetails();
         // print job details for each student
         for (int j = 0; j < indexNo; j++)
         {
            currentJobs[j].getStudentID().equalsIgnoreCase(comp);
            currentJobs[j].printJobDetails();
         }
      }
   }
```